# How to make my own copy of a shared google drive file?

Tags: python, download, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I am running a google colab file(A GAN) and it needs to download a .pkl file(only 310MB) which is needed to run the GAN model. It uses this python line from dnnlib library to download that file in hte code.

```
dlink='https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1N2-m9qszOeVC9Tq77WxsLnuWwOedQiD2'
with dnnlib.util.open_url(dlink_orig, cache_dir=config.cache_dir) as f:
    perc_model =  pickle.load(f)
```

But when downloading the specific file it raises an error like this,

```
raise IOError("Google Drive quota exceeded")
OSError: Google Drive quota exceeded
```

Then I tried to solve the problem by googling for a solution. Then I found this suggestion by a person on the internet to try make a copy of that file and download it from that file(getting the shareable link and get the file_id from that and use it to download the file). But that copied file had this arrow in the files icon. And gave me the **same error**.

Then I googled about the icon and found that the icon means it has created a duplicate which redirects to the same original file(I guess to save space by google by eliminating duplicate file existence). One guy had on the support.google.com has suggested to try make a copy again of that file which I copied once already and try to run the code(which inside tries to download the particular .pkl file in the google drive).

pkl file link - https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1N2-m9qszOeVC9Tq77WxsLnuWwOedQiD2
colab file link - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LBWcmnUPoHDeaYlRiHokGyjywIdyhAQb

[image]

Is there a way to use that pkl file in my google colab file without mounting my google drive, or without downloading it to my local drive and upload it again?

Comment: If your quota has exceeded then you need to wait until midnight west coast usa for the quota to open up again.

Comment: Actually I did not use any services yesterday other than running this code. I think in the initial steps this code consumes my entire quota(If thats the case). I tried today fresh after 24 hours. I still get the error

Comment: Have you checked your project on google developer console to see how much quota you have.   Whats the full error message BTW there are five or six quota exceeded error messages might help to know which one it is.

Comment: I don't use a project related to this on google dev console. I only see my GCP quotas there which I'm not using here. Somehow when I ran the codes today, with only 3 input images(I tried 5 and 6 and 8 earlier because they have asked to use less than 8 images and 3-6 for optimial results. But I don't see a relationship with the number of input images with this error) it worked fine without this error.

Comment: @DaImTo It is not working again. This is the error.     

raise IOError("Google Drive quota exceeded")
OSError: Google Drive quota exceeded